# Как разместить две группы кастомных кнопкок (элементы управления карты) в два ряда на Yandex Maps?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я создаю два набора интерфейсов.
В первом - 1 ряд кнопок, во втором- второй.
Кнопки должны располагаться в левом верхнем углу, набор под набором.
Но получается или все кнопки разместить в 1 ряд и только, или в 2 ряда, но тогда в каждом ряду кнопки не будут знать о существовании о других, и не будут отступать друг от друга и наложатся (разместятся в 0 позиции).
Кнопки создаются с конструктором `new ymaps.control.Button`, где в `options` передаётся `float:left, position: { top: 20, left: 20, }, adjustMapMargin: true,`. Далее просто добавляется в контролы каты `map.controls.add(button);` Для второго набора параметр top перезадан на больший, и так отступ сверху срабатывает, но кнопки в каждом ряду накладываются друг на друга.

https://jsfiddle.net/o2zv6ne0/26/

https://jsfiddle.net/o2zv6ne0/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент в API Яндекс.Карт нет рабочих методов разместить контролы в два ряда с использованием **float**.
При использования **position** **float** переключается на **"none"**, это однозначно определено в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.Button-docpage/#control.Button__param-parameters.options.position).

На данный момент единственным вариантом будет вручную расположить элементы, указав персональный **position** для каждого из них.

Comment: спасибо, увы, невозможно, элементы неопределенного количества с неопределенным размером. Пока размещаем отдельно от карты дивом, но тоже ограничения - блокируется область. Будем выносить за карту вовсе...